# Преобразовать связь сущностей ManyToMany в ManyToOne

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

У меня есть три таблицы, Блюдо,Информация о Блюде и Категория,которые созданы в базе следующим образом:

**dishes**

```sql
CREATE TABLE restaurant_schema.dishes
(
    id           BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name         VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
    price        NUMERIC(7, 2) NOT NULL,
    dish_info_id BIGINT        NOT NULL UNIQUE REFERENCES restaurant_schema.dish_info
);
```

**dish_info**

```sql
CREATE TABLE restaurant_schema.dish_info
(
    id          BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    category_id BIGINT REFERENCES restaurant_schema.categories (id),
    weight      INT NOT NULL,
    recipe_id   BIGINT REFERENCES warehouse_schema.recipes (id)
);
```

**categories**

```sql
CREATE TABLE restaurant_schema.categories
(
    id   BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR(128)
);
```

Мне не нравится структура связей, с одной стороны мне кажется не до конца логичным что в категории(`categories`) хранится информация о блюде(`dish_info`), а не само блюдо(`dish`).
Также я бы хотел видеть связь между блюдом и категорией в виде `ManyToOne`, а не `ManyToMany`, поэтому я думаю создать промежуточную сущность, но проблема в том что в результате получится что в этой сущности будут хранится просто два ключа, что тоже мне кажется не до конца логичным.

Пока что моя объектная модель выглядит следующим образом:

**Dish**

```java
public class Dish {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;

    @Column(name = "price")
    BigDecimal price;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "dish_info_id")
    DishInfo dishInfo;
}
```

**DishInfo**

```java
public class DishInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "weight")
    Integer weight;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    List<Category> categories;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "recipe_id")
    Recipe recipe;
}
```

**Category**

```java
public class Category {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    String name;
}
```

---

Как в моем случает можно улучшить объектную и реляционную модель?
Как бы вы организовали связи?

Буду благодарен любому совету

Comment: " в этой сущности будут хранится просто два ключа,что тоже мне кажется не до конца логичным" - что именно в этом нелогичного? Это промежуточная сущность, если она выполняет роль таким образом, то чему в теории это противоречит?

Comment: @Сергей Меня смущает что промежуточная сущность не несет в ссебе никакой смысловой нагрузки помимо того что обозначает связь двух таблиц

Comment: Есть два уровня связей. Логические (то что идет из предметной области и определяется требованиями) и физические (как именно в БД реализовано хранение логической связи). Для начала нужно получить требования т.е. ответы на вопросы типа: может ли одно блюдо находится в нескольких категориях? Улучшать модель не зная требований - занятие малоперспективное. Ну и второй момент - это то, что модель по хорошему должна отображать логические связи. А сохраненинем модели в БД должен заниматься репозиторий, и там уже может быть преобразование в сущности такие, как нужно для ORM.

Comment: Я только сегодня получил сертификат по MySQL, так что практическим опытом особым не обладаю, но я видел такие вещи в учебных примерах. Но основное (я все же повторю свой вопрос): почему вы считаете, что она обязательно должна нести какую-то еще нагрузку? По её основной задаче она "соединяет между собой две разных сущности соседних таблиц (а также МОЖЕТ содержать дополнительную информацию). " Вот, даже нашел: <https://www.lucidchart.com/pages/ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85>

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA , наверное мне действительно стоило указать это явно,в одной категории может быть много блюд,одно блюдо может быть в нескольких категориях

Comment: Таблица, единственное назначение которой, хранение ассоциации (связи) между сущностями - это нормально. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_entity

Comment: Тогда почему "хотел видеть связь между блюдом и категорией в виде ManyToOne,а не ManyToMany"?

Comment: @SmetanaPoAktsii, позвольте я замечу... Вы говорите: "`хотел видеть связь между блюдом и категорией в виде ManyToOne,а не ManyToMany`",  во избежание чего хотите "`создать промежуточную сущность, ... в которой будут хранится просто два ключа`" ... Смею заметить, что создавая промежуточную сущность с двумя ключами Вы по факту создаете ничто иное как связь `MANY_TO_MANY`, просто вы её оборачиваете сущностью... в остальном же она будет играть ту же самую роль что и таблица, создаваемая при определении данной связи, которая просто хранит два ключа.

Comment: Тут вам стоит самому подумать, понять и решить: может быть отношение к  `MANY_TO_MANY` было предвзятым и желание избавиться от него любой ценой просто заблуждение?

Comment: Также хочу отметить что чисто функционально `MANY_TO_MANY` и `ONE_TO_MANY` отличаются. И данные связи имеют совершенно разные возможности. И тут стоит отталкиваться не столько от желаний, сколько от реальных потребностей. Может ли у Вас одно и то же блюдо одновременно находиться в двух разных категориях? В будущем такое Вы тоже не планируете? Если так то делайте `ONE_TO_MANY`. В противном случае придется делать `MANY_TO_MANY`.

Comment: На данный момент видно, что у вас есть таблица dishes и её логичное продолжение в виде таблицы dish_info, выделение которой не несет полезной нагрузки. Кроме как просто создать еще одну таблицу и делать join в ней смысла нет особо. Второе, у вас сейчас ManyToOne поскольку одно блюдо ссылается на одну категорию. Если у вас требования одно блюдо - несколько категорий и одна категория - несколько блюд, то вам уже требования диктуют создавать ManyToMany без каких-то альтернатив.

Comment: Также хочу отметить, что на данный момент таблица `restaurant_schema.dish_info` НЕ СООТВЕТСТВУЕТ классу `DishInfo`. В таблице у Вас `MANY_TO_ONE`, а в классе `ONE_TO_MANY`... Это ошибка ... в классе у вас должно быть `@ManyToOne Category сategory;`

Comment: Дейвствительно,мое отношение к ManyToMany было предвзятым,оказалось никаких проблем при работе с этим мапингом не возникает. Продублируйте кто-нибудь свой совет в виде ответа и я отмечу его как верный

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы говорите:

> *@Smetana Po Aktsii*:
> хотел видеть связь между блюдом и категорией в виде ManyToOne, а не ManyToMany

, во избежание чего хотите

> *@Smetana Po Aktsii*:
> создать промежуточную сущность, ... в которой будут хранится просто два ключа

Смею заметить, что создавая промежуточную сущность с двумя ключами Вы по факту создаете ничто иное как связь `MANY_TO_MANY`, просто вы её оборачиваете сущностью... в остальном же она будет играть ту же самую роль что и таблица, создаваемая при определении данной связи, которая просто хранит два ключа.

Тут вам стоит самому подумать, понять и решить:
может быть отношение к `MANY_TO_MANY` было предвзятым и желание избавиться от него любой ценой просто заблуждение?

Также хочу отметить что чисто функционально `MANY_TO_MANY` и `ONE_TO_MANY` отличаются.
И данные связи имеют совершенно разные возможности.
И тут стоит отталкиваться не столько от желаний, сколько от реальных потребностей.

- Может ли у Вас одно и то же блюдо одновременно находиться в двух разных категориях?
- В будущем такое Вы тоже не планируете?

Если так то делайте `ONE_TO_MANY`.
В противном случае придется делать `MANY_TO_MANY`.

Также хочу отметить следующее:
на данный момент таблица `restaurant_schema.dish_info` **НЕ СООТВЕТСТВУЕТ** классу `DishInfo`.
В таблице у Вас `MANY_TO_ONE`, а в классе `ONE_TO_MANY`...
**Это ошибка** ... с такой таблицей в классе у вас должно быть

```java
@ManyToOne
Category сategory;
```

Также я присоединюсь к комментарию `@Alex Krass` о том, что на данный момент не вижу необходимости в разделении `Dish` и `DishInfo` на два класса.
Возможно, Вы нам не все рассказали, но из того что мы видим - необходимости в данном разделении нет. 
Я искренне надеюсь, что это не я Вас подтолкнул к действиям.
Больше сущностей не всегда значит лучше, и в том же ответе в другом кейсе я наоборот старался перенести поле в существующий класс, вместо того чтобы создавать ненужную сущность.
С опытом у Вас получится лучше чувствовать такие моменты:
пока же просто держите в голове, что для создания новой сущности нужно очень хорошо понимать для чего именно Вы это делаете.
Если Вы не можете уверенно ответить на этот вопрос, то стоит задуматься...